# MySQL router failed to set destination by metadata cache

Tags: mysql, mysql-innodb-cluster, mysqlrouter

I have a 1 primary 1 secondary mysql innodb cluster with both node have mysql server version  8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 .

I route to the cluster by mysql router, and hope to always visit the primary server with mode ready-write.

I install mysql router by dpkg.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-shell_8.0.35-1ubuntu22.04_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get install -f
$ mysqlsh -V
mysqlsh   Ver 8.0.35 for Linux on x86_64 - for MySQL 8.0.35 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))
```

When I set destinations by hosts, things works properly and I can access the database through port 33061:

```
[routing:read_writer]
bind_address=0.0.0.0
bind_port=33061
mode=read-write
destinations=192.168.9.16:3306,192.168.9.249:3306
max_connections=1024
```

When I set destinations by metadata-cache, though mysqlrouter still starts up, I cannot visit the database, and `/var/logs/mysqlrouter/mysqlrouter.log` does not print new messages.

```
[metadata_cache:testCluster]
cluster_type=gr
router_id=1
user=router
metadata_cluster=testCluster
ttl=0.5

[routing:read_writer]
bind_address=0.0.0.0
bind_port=33061
mode=read-write
# destinations=192.168.9.16:3306,192.168.9.249:3306
max_connections=1024
destinations=metadata-cache://testCluster/?role=PRIMARY
```

Nothing wrong in `journalctl -xeu mysqlrouter`, it just tells me service has been started by successfully.

Could anyone tell me what do I missed?

I mainly refer to the official document as [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/mysql-router-configuration-file-example.html).

There is [a related change](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql-router/8.0/en/news-8-0-35.html) for this version of mysqlrouter, but I tried and nothing changed.

#### In Addition

When I tested and tried to run mysqlrouter with `--bootstrap`, I get the following error:

```
$ mysqlrouter --bootstrap spinq@192.168.9.249:3306 --directory /home/tmp --user=root
Please enter MySQL password for spinq:
Error: Can't set ownership of file '/home/tmp' to the user 'root'. error: Permission denied.
One possible reason can be that the root user does not have proper rights because of root_squash on the NFS share.
```

I simply use a fresh new VMWare machine with Ubuntu22.04. Please tell me why this issue comes up and how to solve it.